# XSD: how to restrict number of characters in string type attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a question regarding adding restriction in my xml schema(xsd). I have a complex-type like:

```
<xsd:complexType name="xxx">
   <xsd:attribute/>
   .....
</xsd:complexType>
```

I have many attributes in this complex-type, and few of them are of string type. Now I want those string type attributes to be restricted to y no. of chars, how do I add this restriction?

Thanks!
-Ankush

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to create a simple type like so:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="LimitedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

and then use this new type in your schema:

```
  <xs:complexType name="test">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:String" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="LimitedString" name="myattr" />
  </xs:complexType>
```

Marc

Answer (score 34):

You can restrict the string to a number of chars like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="threeCharString">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>3-char strings only</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:length value="3"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The **xs:length** in the above limits the length of the string to *exactly* 3 chars. You can also use **xs:minLength** and **xs:maxlength**, or both.

You can provide a pattern like so:

```
<xs:simpleType name="fourCharAlphaString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]{4}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The above says, 4 chars, of any of a-z, A-Z.  The **xs:pattern** is a regular expression, so go to town with it.

You can restrict the string to a particular set of strings in this way:

```
<xs:simpleType name="iso3currency">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>ISO-4217 3-letter currency codes. Only a subset are defined here.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:length value="3"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="AUD"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="BRL"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CAD"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="CNY"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="EUR"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="GBP"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="INR"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="JPY"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="RUR"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="USD"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: the xs:length however requires the string to be the defined exact length - it doesn't just limit the maximum length.

Comment: the xs:length is redundant, since the enumeration already defines all acceptable values as having three characters.

Answer (score 17):

The answer by marc_s would require you to define a new type for every possible string length you might use. Instead you can define the restriction directly on the attribute itself.

```
  <xs:complexType name="Test">
    <xs:attribute name="LimitedString">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value = "50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Add this and it worked for me,**

```
<xs:element  name="vendor">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>80-char strings only</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: You might want to consider explaining how to implement what you are suggesting with a code sample. Your answer is not clear at the moment

Answer (score 0):

you can always define the maximal length of a string in xsd.
Just add the attribute `maxLength` resp. `minLength`.