# JAXB @XmlElement with string length limit (generated XSD simple type)

Tags: xsd, jaxb, wsdl, maxlength, simpletype

JAXB `@XmlElement` with string length limit (generated XSD simple type)

I use Java to generate a SOAP webservice.
Therefore, this is a code first approach

In Java I have a String field, on which I like to have a length limit of 50 characters.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ContactTO {

  private String comment; 

  @XmlElement
  public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
  }
}

public class ContactWebService implements ContactServiceIf {

  @Override
  public ContactTO createContact(@WebParam(name = "newContact") ContactTO newContact)
  ...
```

> http://localhost:12080/services/contactService?wsdl

Is showing:

```
<xs:complexType name="contactTO">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comment" type="xs:string" />
```

How can I limit the comment element to a length of 50?

I'd like to have something like this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="LimitedString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Or something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="fourCharAlphaString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]{4}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But I can't manually edit the inline (generated) xsd in the wsdl.

Thank you very much.

(note: [XSD: how to restrict number of characters in string type attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966948/xsd-how-to-restrict-number-of-characters-in-string-type-attribute))

(note: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp)

Thanks, 
Reto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JAXB support xsd:restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775465/does-jaxb-support-xsdrestriction)